# Is there any difference when including compressed/uncompressed vendor assets in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, compression, sprockets, uglifyjs

Let's say I want to include jquery-ui in my Rails 3 application.

I can include the uncompressed version:

```
//= require jquery-ui
```

or the compressed version:

```
//= require jquery-ui.min
```

Sprockets will compress any of them using uglifier by default.

Could the result be significantly different according to the way you loaded the asset?

Which way would you go? Why?